# How to launch a python script from java ee?

Tags: java, python, jakarta-ee, web

I usually do `python example.py` in terminal for execution. Can we do this in Java? Can we launch a python script from java ? Because I want to launch some python commands from my website Java EE. I don't mean to execute the python code in java, but just let java to call python to do it.

**example.py**

```
print "hello world"
```

Is it possible ? Where should I get started ?